# How to show data stored in Liferay database in another website?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, liferay, portlet

I'm developing a WordPress website in which I have to show data/information stored inside a Liferay database. I am new to Liferay, so I don't know the best practices to access data stored into Liferay's DB and show them to my website.

I want to know if there are some guides or documentation that can explain to me how I can access data, in the same way that I access a MySQL DB with PHP. I also took a look at the official Liferay documentation, but it only describes accesses through the usage of PHP portlets.

Is there another way to connect to database and get back data from a query, or do I have to perform a sort of "middleware" translation from data in Liferay to my website?

My CMS contains data formatted in XML, so have I to do a translation from XML to PHP-style variables? Also, do I need to create a sort of correspondence from XML objects to PHP variables?

Comment: Did you already start here: https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/user-guide/-/ai/web-content-management-liferay-portal-6-2-user-guide-02-en ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of three ways you can get data from Liferay to display in your website:

1. Directly through Liferay database, if you have access.

   But to get data directly from the Database tables of liferay you should have a fair amount of understanding as to what each table is for. Liferay DB schema would have been helpful but I think Liferay likes providing puzzles to its users ;-). Still the tables and columns are not so complex to understand if you can give some time. Or post a specific query and will answer if I know about it.
2. Another recommended way of accessing liferay's data is through [Liferay web-services](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/accessing-services-remotely-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-05-en), all the assets, users, organizations and sites are available as services. So you can build web-service clients and consume the data.
3. Another way is through [Sharing of Portlets](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/user-guide/-/ai/sharing-liferay-portal-6-2-user-guide-04-en). The User-guide will help you understand this. You can directly embed portlets in your site just like we can embed video player from youtube in any site with youtube's embed script.

Hope I have understood what you require and hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Prakash, I will start developing portlets because for my scope I think it's the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted answer on behalf of the OP).*

I've found a solution that matches my problem. I found [WordPress All Import](http://www.wpallimport.com/) plugin.

With this plugin I can browse and use my Liferay's database content to populate posts, by passing an XML/CVS file. Liferay allows to get XML format of the database's entries, so that's it.